# Kibana3 - Graph to plot amount of bytes per minute

Tags: kibana

I have apache logs with size of each request and the time , I need to plot graph on amount of data transfered per unit time.

A sample document looks like below

```
{
    "@timestamp" : "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
    "bytes" : 20
}
```

For each minute , I want to take sum of the bytes field and plot that over a graph in Kibana 3. Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by editing the panel settings,as shown in the figure below:
[image]

1. "Values" dropdown: Select the value to be "total" from this.
2. Values Field : The field which is to be analysed. Here in your case it is "values"
3. "Time Field" : the timefield in your data,ie "@timestamp"
4. "interval" : set as "1m" here.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using a histogram panel.

- Under values, set 'chart value' to 'total' and use bytes as the value field
- Check that 'time field' is @timestamp
- Untick auto-interval and set the interval to be '1m'